# SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'test'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: php, mysql, yii2, mariadb, digital-ocean

I have install mariadb 10.2 on Digitalocean droplet. I have created test@localhost user and granted access to test database.

With test user I can able log into mysql console.

But when I am trying to connect to database from my Yii2 Application, access denied with password arises.

I have run mysql_secure_connection script to block root access from outside.

My DB Config -

Database Component Config:

```
return [
    'class' => 'yii\db\Connection', 
    'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 
    'username' => 'test', 
    'password' => 'test@123', 
    'charset' => 'utf8',
];
```

Does anyone has any idea.

Comment: You must be sending the wrong password in the application.

Comment: where is your database component configuration add it to your question?

Comment: Database Component Config - 
return [
    'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
    'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test',
    'username' => 'test',
    'password' => 'test@123',
    'charset' => 'utf8',
];

Comment: try adding it into the question not in comments

Comment: Were you able to resolve your issue?

Comment: Yes. Had to remove existing permissions for user to database and reassign.

Answer (score 1):

use localhost:3306 instead of using host=local

Answer (score 0):

Try addin a new db user and use % for any host. See if you still are receiving the error. Attempt to connect to your DB via MySQL workbench, verify your credentials.

Did you deny remote access?

```
'db' => [
    'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
    'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost; dbname=somedb',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => 'passw0rd',
    'charset' => 'utf8',
]
```