# CDbConnection failed to open the DB connection: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) YII2 in local

Tags: php, mysql, yii

So I just downloaded yii2 project from server using Winscp to run it in my local, but when I run it gives me the error: `CDbConnection failed to open the DB connection: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`. I've checked the user privileges and I've grant all privileges. [(user table mysql)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbzic.png).

Here's the main.php:

```
'db'=>array(
        'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=serena',
        'emulatePrepare' => true,
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
    ),
```

Comment: using password: `NO` ? (First off, please set a password for root for security, and please create a separate mysql user account with password and necessary privileges for accessing the db)

Comment: still gives me error. Access denied for user 'tommy'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: I've checked all privileges and grant it all

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQLSTATE\[HY000\] \[1045\] Access denied for user 'test'@'localhost' (using password: YES)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49824312/sqlstatehy000-1045-access-denied-for-user-testlocalhost-using-password)

Answer (score 0):

I just adding the port because I have different port.

```
 'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=serena;port=8111',
```